# WSDL connection throws an ADBException

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, wsdl, xmlhttprequest

In my app i am using WSDl webservice.And try to call webservice method.
In that request send successfuly and also get response.But when i fetch that response using following method:

```
     // Called when the connection has finished loading.
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSError* error;
    if(self.logging == YES) {
        NSString* response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: self.receivedData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"response=%@", response);
        [response release];
    }
```

It gives following exception.
And my NSLog statement shows following details:

```
response=<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode><faultstring>org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement {http://services.webservices.sparta.com}sSessionId</faultstring><detail /></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please suggest me the way to solve  this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide more description about web service and parameters you pass into it. So that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

From the question description we can not exactly figure out problem.

But from your log I can give you some suggestion to check your code :

```
<soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode><faultstring>
```

1) You may be passing wrong number of parameters to web-service.

2) The parameter `data type` may `not be matching`. for example, you are passing `string` where server accepting `integer` or vice-versa.

3) Or `web-service having some problem`.

you can also search on [org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException%3a%20Unexpected%20subelement&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a). There are many useful links which may help you to figure out whether problem is at your web-service or in your iphone coding.